# What is the most accurate way to assign unique ID to each visitor?

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for an accurate way to assign an ID to each visitor to my website. If they return they must keep the same ID. My current method is having lots of miss fires and is assigning new IDs to returning visitors.. obviously this can change with device, IP, etc..

At the moment, when my site gets a new visitor it will log their IP in the database, the ID will become their ID.. when they return we do a lookup to see if their IP is matched,  obviously this is not reliable it could easily return more than one, if it does we then look for ip and user agent.

In total we do 3 checks:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

If we can't find an entry that matches all 3 then we class this as a new visitor.

Is there a better method?

Comment: write cookies to their local machine?

Comment: Cookies are not only machine specific they are browser specific and 90% of our traffic is mobile, and the majority of that will be the built in Facebook browser so I'm thinking it would be impossible to track them via cookie? Unless i'm not thinking along the same lines as you?

Comment: put the id inside the cookie. your _own_ id format _can't_ be browser-specific

Comment: The only way to track them is with a cookie in the browser or flash cookie or similar. Ad sites etc are keen on using cookie, flash cookie, 3rd party image with etag, etc.